# Clickable links from string with links end text

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I need to make text with links to webpages. I use that code but is not working:

```
licence = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.about_text5);
final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml("The ipiit Team\n\nFYI:        This software contains the <a href=\"http://code.google.com/p/zxing\">zxing</a> component licensed under <a href=\"http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/license.html\">Apache 2.0</a>.\n\n"));
Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
licence.setText(s);
licence.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be...

```
Linkify.addLinks(licence , Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

and not

```
Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

because you are already setting your Spannable text to your `TextView`, so call addLinks on the `TextView`...